# Remove a column from CSV file in Notepad++

Tags: csv, dataset, notepad++

First of all, I'm a newbie in Notepad++. I'm trying to edit this dataset in Notepad++, which is stored in CSV. I can't open this file in Excel as there are some cells containing digits longer than 15 and Excel will convert these digits.

The column headings are like this,

```
BNFUniqueID,username,CollectTeam,Hos_methodID,CollectData,hhstatus,hhupazila,hhunion,hhlocationsitetype,hhsitename,hhlocalblock,villagename,hhlandmark,hhmajiname,hhmajitel,HoHname,Hhsize,HoHcontact,cardtype,cardnum,olduniqueID,BNFname,BNFage,BNFsex,BNFagegroup
```

In this dataset there is a column (`hhlandmark`) in the middle and I'm trying to delete this whole column. One of the problem is that, not all the cells contain data, so the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> isn't suitable for this task, as vertical selection would block cells from other columns as well.

I'm looking for a way to avoid this and delete only the column I want to delete.

Comment: Are the number of _commas_ the same in every row of the file?  Or, does missing columns also mean missing commas?

Comment: number of commas are same in each row of the file, but between commas there could be no data for some row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 12 columns before the `hhlandmark` column, so we can try the following find and replace in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^((?:[^,]*,){12})[^,]*,(.*)$
Replace: $1$2
```

This pattern says to match:

- `^` from the start of the line

  - `((?:[^,]*,){12})` match and capture in `$1` the first 12 columns
  - `[^,]*,` then match the 13th column (hhlandmark)
  - `(.*)` match and capture in the `$2` the rest of the line
- `$` end of the line

We then replace with `$1$2` to effectively splice out the 13th `hhlandmark` column.

Here is a running regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQpmSJ/2).

Comment: Thanks Tim, as I said I'm totally newbie in Notepad++, so I tried the regex and replace, but it's not working, would you please tell me the step I need to follow to execute this, I need to delete the whole column.

Comment: @4vi I have fixed my answer, which now does not assume that a missing column will have any characters at all.  Try the pattern again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about notepad++, but you could do this easily using pandas library of python.